# A property of directed graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Please help me solve this problem:

Give a weak connected, simple, directed graph G. Prove that S = sum(abs(degIn(u)-degOut(u))) is even.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this statement is true for any graph G that has no edges.

Suppose G is a graph that has at least one edge. Let e = (u, v) be any edge in G. Suppose G - e satisfies the property. Now examine G. Between G - e and G, the value of abs(degin(w) - degout(w)) remains the same for all vertices other than u and v. The values for u and v both change by exactly 1, for a total change of either -2, 0, or 2. Therefore the sum(abs(degin(w) - degout(w)) is even for G.

By induction on the number of edges in G, all graphs G satisfy the property.